# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Task should be completed.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, crash-reports, sigabrt

I have no idea why I am seeing this error. Any help would be appreciated. This is causing my app to crash and it is not reproducible. [image]

Comment: Are you using parse.com? I found that message in their source code and it would be triggered if you are doing something bad with tasks. See https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/913

Comment: Yes. We recently migrated from Parse and also updated the framework. Not sure why I am seeing this.